# How install xcode X GM in parallel with current xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm talking about the GM version. It's not stable enough to get rid of xcode 4. But I'd like to start playing with the new stuff. Is it sufficient to drag it out of the dmg to the desktop and rename it, or is this going to lead to issues once it is dragged into applications?

Comment: Rename the original Xcode.app to Xcode4.app or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

When you double click to instal it will pop ask you, to overwrite or keep both. Just keep both. Worked for me

Comment: Yes, mine is Xcode 2 - cant recall if you can pick your own name... maybe u can as well.

Comment: When i click it ask to drag on Application folder. is it ok. I alos want to use both.

Comment: @CRDDave You only want to drag it to the app folder if you answer "keep both" to the dialogue, in which case it will rename one of them, or you rename the existing one, and then drag the new one over, or you drag it somewhere else and rename it before dragging it in, otherwise it will overwrite your existing xcode.

Answer (score 4):

Once you extract the app from .dmg the window will be shown with Xcodes' large icon and Application folder. and it will say "Drag XCode Icon to Application Folder to install"(Something like that).

Before doing that, goto application folder just rename the existing Xcode version. And then do the drag and drop.

now you have both versions !

Answer (score 3):

Create New folder in Applications with any name like - "Xcode 5 GM" (whatever new Xcode version, You just need to create folder for that in Applications)
Mount DMG file then Find Xcode file then Drag this file to Application/Xcode 5 GM  what you have created earlier.
After file copied go and launch that file to complete installation.

Comment: This worked for me on my MacBookPro with XCode 4 and XCode 5. I created a new folder called 'XCode 5' in Applications and dragged XCode.app from the DMG into the folder. As noted in other answers, 'xcode-select' is a key element for using this setup from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all the complication; I install Xcode 4 in `/Applications` (pretty much have to as it's installed from the MAS) and Xcode 5 in `~/Applications`.

The only thing to do then is run `xcode-select` to ensure the correct command line utilities are used from, err, the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Xcode 5 and wrote detail instructions [Install both Xcode 4 and Xcode 5](http://www.fantageek.com/611/install-both-xcode-4-and-xcode-5/), especially on how to reuse the old SDKs and Simulators.

Hope it helps